# python input being read wrong?

Tags: python, user-interface, controls

My problem is that after python first reads the raw input it no longer correctly reads inputs subsequently afterwards. I've tried a lot of things but I can't seem to get it. What am I doing wrong?

```
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Neo\\My Documents\\Python Scripts\\FTC Scouting\\sample.txt'
file = open(file_path, 'r')
Team_Numbers = []

tNum = 'Team Number: '
tName = 'Name: '
ui = ''

def list_teams(n):
    count = 0
    if n == '1':
        for line in file:
            check = line.find(tNum)
            if not check == -1:        
                print line[len(tNum):]    #prints everything after the Team Number: 
            count += 1

    elif n == 2:
        for line in file:
            check = line.find(tName)
            if not check == -1:
                print line[len(tName):]    #prints everything after the Team Number: 
            count += 1

while not ui == 'end':

    ui = raw_input('1: to list Team Numbers\n2: to list Names\n')
    list_teams(ui)


file.close()
```

Comment: what's the `count` variable for?

Answer (score 6):

Python is strongly typed.

```
elif n == '2':
```

Answer (score 3):

It's reading your *input* fine. It's just that when you've read a file once, you're done; the file doesn't magically start reading again from the beginning the next time you iterate over it. So your `for line in file:` works once and then doesn't work again because there's nothing in the file after the end! To fix this, just put `file.seek(0)` at the end of your `list_teams()` function; this will reset the file to the beginning.

There are probably other problems too (Ignacio found a bug and there are other optimizations to be made) but this is probably your immediate issue.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that after it goes through the first iteration that it didn't start reading all over again.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a re-look of code to make it more Pythonic, reduce redundancy and add readability

First Your repetitive code block which you can easily overcome by using `list` or dictionary or named tuples, just an example with `list`

```
keys = ['Team Number: ', 'Name: ']
def list_teams(n):
    count = 0
    try:
        for line in file:
            check = line.find(keys[n])
            if not check == -1:        
                print line[len(keys[n]):]    #prints everything after the Team Number: 
            count += 1
except IndexError:
    None #Or Any appropriate Error Checking
```

Now the second part. Instead of using find and then indexing, you can simply use `string.partition`

```
keys = ['Team Number: ', 'Name: ']
def list_teams(n):
    count = 0
    try:
        for line in file:
            print line.partition(keys[n])[2]
            count += 1
except IndexError:
    None #Or Any appropriate Error Checking
```

And finally it seems, multiple calls to list_teams would fail, as because you are reacing the end. One solution would be

```
keys = ['Team Number: ', 'Name: ']
def list_teams(n):
    count = 0
    with open(file_path,'r') as f:
        try:
            for line in file:
                print line.partition(keys[n])[2]
                count += 1
    except IndexError:
        None #Or Any appropriate Error Checking
```

Alternatively you can always seek to the beginning before reading the file.

```
keys = ['Team Number: ', 'Name: ']
def list_teams(n):
    file.seek(0)
    count = 0
    try:
        for line in file:
            print line.partition(keys[n])[2]
            count += 1
except IndexError:
    None #Or Any appropriate Error Checking
```

Comment: thanks! This did wonders for my understanding of keys and using python in genral